# Change margin on hover but keep element stationary

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, margin

I have a simple JSFiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/cppvf4eb/

When hovering over the green block, I would like two push the other two blocks away by 10 pixels. Currently I use this code for the effect:

```
#block2:hover {
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

The current behavior keeps the blue block stationary, but I want the green block to stay put. Maybe margin isn't the best solution to this, let me know if there are better. **I would prefer a CSS only solution if it exists.**

**Clarification**: The end goal is to be able to hover over each individual block and create a 10px space between any bordering block. I don't mind the end blocks shifting position, but for the middle block, I'd like an effect that leaves it stationary, and instead pushes the other two away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fiddle should fit your need:

```
.row:hover {
    margin: 0px -10px;
}

.row .block:hover {
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qmm1m3wh/3/

Answer (score 1):

Give the margin to the hovered block, adjust that margin on the container:

```css
.row {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.block {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.row:hover {
    margin: 0px 40px;
}
.block:hover {
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
#block1 {background-color: blue}
#block2 {background-color: green}
#block3 {background-color: red}
#block4 {background-color: orange}
#block5 {background-color: yellow}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div id="block1" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block2" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block3" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block4" class="block"></div>
    <div id="block5" class="block"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

what about listening for a hover on the parent div?

```
.row:hover #block1 {
    margin: 0px -10px;
}

.row:hover #block2 {
    margin: 0px 10px 0 20px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cppvf4eb/1/

Comment: I should have specified...I need a different hover animation for each block, so having one overarching animation won't do.

Comment: then @Matteo425 has generalized this approach to the general case in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had got an similar issue with 3D button (:hover action press it).
I neeeded to change all the properties with animations (all) over the time expect one because the total height of the element grown up by changing the margin (logic).

The effect was that all of the next elements where puhsing too.
Basically, to solve the problem, I made a **reverse margin-transition**.
If the margin-top was increse by 3, I decrese the margin-bottom as well.

**Exemple :**

```
.btn-default {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  border-color: @border-color;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 @border-color;
  background-color: @background-color-light;
  color: @color;
  transition: @btn-default-time-transition linear; /* vendorless fallback */
  -o-transition: @btn-default-time-transition linear; /* opera */
  -moz-transition: @btn-default-time-transition linear; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-transition: @btn-default-time-transition linear; /*safari and chrome */
}

.btn-default:hover {
  margin-top: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 0 @border-color;
  border-color: @border-color;
  background-color: @background-color-light-hover;
  color: @color-hover;
}
```

And tada!